# Bootstrap navbar x-scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change the behaviour of the Bootstrap navbar to inherit a horizontal scroll instead of collapsing, it works on mobile but I want it to be the same across all devices... using SASS:

```
.navbar-nav {
  li {
    display: inline-block; // stops menu items from stacking
  }
}
.scroll {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll; // scroll
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Here is an image of it in mobile view, it works great:
[image]

As I increase the size of the view port and media queries kick in it completely disabled the horizontal scroll:

[image]

And finally on desktop:

[image]

HTML:

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav scroll">
  <li><a href="#">Hyperlink</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hyperlink</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret hidden-xs"></span></a>
    ...
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Hyperlink</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hyperlink</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hyperlink</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hyperlink</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hyperlink</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hyperlink</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way I can keep the x-scroll throughout the entire site? I can't pin point the CSS that is changing it's behaviour. As an added bonus I also need .navbar and .navbar-header to remain inline because that is stacking as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `overflow-x: auto;`. This will work when the viewport size its minor of width stablished.

```
.scroll {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto; 
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x3L06cv8/

Comment: Exactly what I needed: `overflow-x: auto`

Answer (score 9):

Newer versions of Bootstrap make use of the flex-elements a lot and I ran into a similar challenge with Bootstrap 4.5.3, I ended up changing the CSS flex-wrap-property to nowrap.

Since the answers here are related to Bootstrap 3.3.5 (or even older), they are not useful for current Bootstrap Versions.

For current versions, there is no need to convert the flex-elements (li { display: block } in this case) to inline-blocks. Depending on the CSS props, flex elements handle the children as something similar to inline-block if the CSS-prop flex-direction is row.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#overview

Without modifying/adding CSS classes I ended up with this:

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav text-nowrap flex-nowrap" style="overflow-x: auto;">
      ...
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternative with an additional CSS class on the nav:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <style>
      .flex-scroll-x {
        overflow-x: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav flex-scroll-x">...</ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish to have your work on JSfiddle or something.
But what i'm thinking is that you're not using media queries right, there's a range that doesn't have the css code applied to it properly.

So you should play with the media queries, try to make them all with max-width :
@media (max-width:...)
and when it comes to the desktop media query, make it with min-width:1200px or whatever width you like to have, so it'll be for all devices bigger than that width.

And for the brand, try make this for it:

```
.navbar-nav{
position:absolute;
margin-left:10%; /* Or change it as your needs */
}
```

Or else, make a div tag that have navbar-header and navbar-nav inside it, and apply a display property like you did for the li tags for both of the inside elements.
Like this example that i made:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .all div,ul,li{
            display:inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="all">
        <div>Hahaha</div>
        <ul>
            <li>jlshqdm</li>
            <li>jlshqdm</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 5.3 and recent versions you can simply add the built-in `flex-nowrap` and `overflow-x-auto` classes:

```
<ul class="nav nav-underline flex-nowrap overflow-x-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```